# Javascript how to detect Chrome on windows

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome

I have an issue that only shows up in Chrome running on Windows.  How can I detect that the browser is Chrome and the OS is Windows?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific browser and platform detection is rarely the ideal way to solve a problem.  Generally, it is better to identify what specific feature (or bug) you want to detect and design a piece of Javascript to detect that condition rather than try to detect a specific brand and platform of browser.  There are a whole bunch of reasons that feature or bug detection is better.

If you can describe what specific issue you're dealing with, we can perhaps help with how to identify that condition via feature detection rather than browser detection.

Some of the reasons that feature/bug detection is better are:

1. When the feature/bug is implemented or fixed, your code will just "do the right thing" and automatically adapt to the correct behavior.
2. The userAgent string is not entirely accurate and can be spoofed by other browsers or even changed by the user in some cases.
3. Some time in the future when a browser behavior is changed/fixed, now you have to switch to specific version detection to decide exactly which version should have which behavior applied to it.

All that said, there is a userAgent string in the Javascript variable: `navigator.userAgent`.  Here's a recent Chrome/Windows user agent string (you can find hundreds of them listed on the web):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
```

The expression:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") !== -1 && 
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows") !== -1)
```

would test for the presence of both of those characteristics in the user agent.

Comment: You mentioned a very important point, and it is that user agent sniffing is inaccurate. In the example you give, Microsoft Edge, Opera and a few others (Vivaldi, Sleipnir) would match that condition (their user agent contains both strings, "Windows" and "Chrome").

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
var os = navigator.platform;
```